# AuthorizeView Roles siempre me da error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

Estoy probando el  con Blazor WASN y NetCore 7.

He cogido la aplicación que se genera, en el index.razor del cliente he puesto:

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@using System.Security.Claims
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<AuthorizeView>
  <Authorized>
    USARIO AUTORIZADO
  </Authorized>
  <NotAuthorized>
    USARIO NO AUTORIZADO
  </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
<AuthorizeView Roles="admin">
  <Authorized>
    Admin OK
  </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
<AuthorizeView Roles="user">
  <Authorized>
    User OK
  </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
<AuthorizeView Roles="yo">
  <Authorized>
    Yo OK
  </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
<AuthorizeView Roles="user">
  <Authorized>
    User OK
  </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
<AuthorizeView Roles="yo, user">
    User y Yo Ok
  </AuthorizeView>
```

En el program.cs del servidor:

```
using Bl74.Server.Data;
using Bl74.Server.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
  .AddRoles<IdentityRole>() //<--- PARA LOS ROLES
  .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>() //<--- PARA LOS ROLES
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddOptions();
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
  {
  app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
  app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
  }
else
  {
  app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
  // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
  app.UseHsts();
  }

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

Ejecuto la aplicación, me registro con un usuario, me voy a la base de datos y en la tabla [AspNetRoles] me he creado 5 Roles y en la tabla [AspNetUserRoles] pongo el id del usuario y un id de [AspNetRoles]

Siempre obtengo errores del tipo:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
      RolesAuthorizationRequirement:User.IsInRole must be true for one of the following roles: (yo|user)
```

No coge níngun rol.

Si en alguna pagina pongo @attribute [Authorize(Roles = "user")], mismo resultado, dice que no tengo permiso.

He probado diferentes configuraciones en el program, pero siempre igual.

Me falta algo, pero no doy.

Gracias

Comment: Encuentro que es un lio el tema del Login en .net y además como se hace una sola vez por proyecto como que nunca se termina por comprender bien. Hasta donde yo entiendo en Blazor debes tener una clase derivada de `AuthenticationStateProvider` que es la mantiene el estado de la autorización y se setea en el program de Blazor `            builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthStateProvider>();`, tu tienes algo así?

Comment: No, no tengo nada parecido. En la pagina de microsoft tampoco dice nada de eso. No entiendo por qué lo complican tanto. En algún ejemplo he visto algo parecido, pero en otros nada de nada

Answer (score 0):

Después de una semana buscando, en está página vi la solución
https://www.blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/2

Este el program.cs correcto que me ha funcionado:

```
using BL06.Server.Data;
using BL06.Server.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddSession();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
      .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
      .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();


builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
               .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options => {
                 options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("role");
                 options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("role");
               });
// Need to do this as it maps "role" to ClaimTypes.Role and causes issues
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler
    .DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("role");

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();//para usuario


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
  {
  app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
  app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
  }
else
  {
  app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
  // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
  app.UseHsts();
  }

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

Por si a alguien le sirve